# How to use second prisma client in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

I am trying to use a second Prisma client in my project:

[image]

Here is the Client.ts for Prisma:

```
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the Client2.ts for Prisma2:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('../../prisma2/generated/client2');
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal {
  prisma2: typeof PrismaClient;
}
declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;
const prisma2 = global.prisma2 || new PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  global.prisma2 = prisma2;
}
prisma2.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
  console.log('beforeExit hook');
  // PrismaClient still available
  await prisma2.$disconnect();
});
export default prisma2;
```

I can run my project and access the database (prisma and prisma2) by using the config above.
However, if I run the e2e test, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '../../prisma2/generated/client2' from '../src/client2.ts'
```

I rewrite the Client2.ts to this:

```
import { PrismaClient as PrismaClient2 } from '../prisma2/generated/client2';
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
  prisma2: PrismaClient2;
}

// Prevent multiple instances of Prisma Client in development
declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;

const prisma2 =
  global.prisma2 ||
  new PrismaClient2({
    log: ['query'],
  });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') global.prisma2 = prisma2;

export default prisma2;
```

This will leave me:

```
Cannot use namespace 'NodeJS' as a value
Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your tsconfig

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

And add @types/node@x.x.x.x in your version for devDependency